# SELECT * FROM table Where CURDATE()

Tags: mysql

I have table product :

- id : int;
- name : varchar(255);
- date_operation : datetime;

And i have some data in my table :

```
1, product1, 2016-08-19 11:10:00
2, product2, 2016-08-19 13:25:00
3, product3, 2016-08-20 07:05:00
4, product4, 2016-08-20 07:10:00
5, product5, 2016-08-20 07:25:00
```

I would like to view the products of today.

Example : today is: 2016-08-20

```
3, product3, 2016-08-20 07:05:00
4, product4, 2016-08-20 07:10:00
5, product5, 2016-08-20 07:25:00
```

I try with this code :

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE date_operation = CURDATE()
```

But i have no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you need `date(date_operation)` (you have datetime)

```
 SELECT * FROM product WHERE date(date_operation)  = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the date part of your datetime column

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE date(date_operation) = CURDATE()
```

else you compare it with the timepart 00:00:00

2016-08-20 07:05:00 is not equals 2016-08-20 00:00:00